# how to add anchor and still have dropdown menu effects show properly

Tags: html, css, dropdown

Firstly I just want to say thank everyone for everything I've learned through reading the threads. I am new to css and only know the basics of html, and just started playing around with them a week ago so I am not too familiar with the syntax.

Here's my question:

Below is my original code which works perfectly and shows the desired dropdown menu effects.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

.dropdownmenu{
    margin: auto;
    }
.dropdownmenu:hover{
        background-color: #2E2E2E;
    }   

$menu_WIDTH: 15px;

.menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer!important;
}

.menu-title {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  width: $menu_WIDTH;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 0 0;
  background: #00000;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: 0.3s background-color;
}

.menu-title:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 101;
  transition:
    0.2s 0.2s border-top ease-out,
    0.3s border-top-color;
}

.menu-dropdown {
  width: auto;  
  position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;  
  background: #ebebeb;
  z-index: 100;
  transition:
    0.5s padding,
    1.0s background;
  padding: 6px 0 6px 0;     
}

.menu-dropdown:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: auto; 
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 101;
  transition: 0.5s border-top;

}

.menu:not(:hover) > .menu-dropdown {

    margin-left: auto;
    width: 143px;
  background: #272727;
  z-index: 99;
}

.menu:not(:hover) > .menu-dropdown:after {
  border-top-color: #dddddd;
}

.menu:not(:hover) > .menu-title:after {
  border-bottom-color: #dddddd;

}

.menu-dropdown > * {
  overflow: hidden;

  height: 50px; 
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: 
    0.5s height cubic-bezier(.73,.32,.34,1.5),
    0.5s padding cubic-bezier(.73,.32,.34,1.5),
    0.5s margin cubic-bezier(.73,.32,.34,1.5),
    0.5s 0.2s color,
    0.2s background-color;
}

.menu-dropdown > *:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

}

.menu:not(:hover) > .menu-dropdown > * {
  visibility: hidden!important;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: rgba(25,25,25,0);
  transition: 
    0.5s 0.1s height,
    0.5s 0.1s padding,
    0.5s 0.1s margin,
    0.3s color,
    0.6s visibility;
  z-index: 99;
}     

.navbar-nav {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdownmenu">
    <a href="#click" class="menu">
      <h2 class="menu-title" style="padding: 40px">services</h2>
      <ul class="menu-dropdown"> 
        <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As soon as I add an anchor with link to each menu item, eg.

```
<li class="item"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
```

the dropdown menu stops hiding before hover like it's supposed to. I also notice an extra item at the top of the list for some reason. I have tried everything, such as changing some of the class names in the css section and adding li a after .menu-dropdown, for example, but to no avail.

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: For me to help you; please provide a JSFiddle (or your preffered online IDE) with your dropdown working as you said in your question, because when I copy your code into a fiddle it doesn't work. Just from scanning your code though, I do suspect your `<a>` tag wrapping the whole dropmenu (why?) and your extensive use of the `*` selector is likely causing competing values / your css targeting the wrong intended element.

Comment: Ok thanks! I will try to figure out how to add JSFiddle to the post!

Comment: I have added the Code Snippet! @Cooleronie

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't edit your original code because the snippet is so buggy already - I can't see what your desired effect is.

However, because I don't want to leave you hanging, I wrote a quick mock-up that I think should come close to how you want your `dropdown` to behave. Hopefully it's of use to you.

**Transitions**

This dropdown has a `transition` effect on 3 properties: `transform`, `opacity` and `height`. The transition on `transfrom: translateY()` makes the whole `dropdown-menu` appear to roll down and `opacity` lets the `dropdown-menu` transition from fully transparent to visible. Lastly, the `height` on each `<li>` element is animated using your defined `cubic-bezier` curve.

You can add as many properties to be animated as your heart desires, just make sure you set an initial value of the property you wish to be animated. For example, I set an initial `height: 0` on `.dropdown-menu li`, and `height: 50px` on the `li` elements when `dropdown` is hovered.

**Implementation**

You can add as many `<li>` elements as you like, the dropdown will continue to work. Inside each `<li>` is an achor tag, as you wished for.

You can change the `display` property on `.dropdown` depending on your implemenatation in your navbar. I set it to `inline-block` so I can give it a `min-width` for this example. Note that the `dropdown-menu` is set to be a `100% width` of its parent: `dropdown`, but you can easily give it a fixed width if you so please.

If you have any questions about this code, don't hesitate to ask. Happy coding.

```css
/* RESET FOR SNIPPET */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

/* DROPDOWN CSS  */

.dropdown {
  --transition-speed: 500ms;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 143px;
}

  .dropdown .dropdown-title {
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
    min-width: 100%;
    transform: translateY(-25px);
    transform-origin: top;
    opacity: 0;
    
    /* transitions the transform property & opacity on hover */
    transition: all var(--transition-speed) ease-out;
  }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
      display: block;
      transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-menu li {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: center;
      height: 0;
      padding: 5px 20px;
      
      /* transitions the height on hover */
      transition: all var(--transition-speed) cubic-bezier(0.73, 0.32, 0.34, 1.5);
    }
  
      .dropdown-menu li:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      }

      .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu li {
        height: 50px;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown-title">Services</div>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br>
    <span>Some text for demonstrating the opacity transition.</span>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much!! This works well and I will continue to play around with it :D